# Where did I make a mistake when trying to make a Django query via AJAX?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I have a page that is basically a storefront with items for sale.  I have some filters in the nav bar to filter product.  When I click a filter, I am trying to get the products related to that filter to load (without refreshing the page) via ajax.

I have been following a tutorial, but I can't get it working.  Currently when I click the filter, I actually see the products on the page flickr for a second, but the same products stay on the page. I know I did not make a mistake in the query itself because I've tried different queries such as reordering by date, ordering by name, ect.

Anyway here is my code below, and if it helps, here is the tutorial I tried to follow http://westiseast.co.uk/blog/django-ajax-update-queryset-introduction/

I am also getting this error in the chrome dev console:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/storefront/?xhr=true&filter=recent 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
```

VIEWS.PY

```
def storefront(request):
    latest_entries = Entry.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:16]
    context = {'latest_entries': latest_entries}

    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.GET.get('filter') == 'recent':
            new_list = []
            latest_entries = Entry.objects.filter(entrytype=3)
            new_list.append(render_to_string('storefrontload.html', {'latest_entries': latest_entries}))
            json =  simplejson.dumps(new_list, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
            return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='application/json')
    return render(request, 'storefront.html', context)
```

URLS.PY

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r"^$", home),
    url(r"^storefront/", storefront))
```

STOREFRONT.HTML

```
<a href="" id=most_recent>Show Recent</a>

{% include "storefrontload.html" %}

<script>
function filter(type) {
$.getJSON("/storefront/", {xhr: "true", filter: type},
  function(data) {
    $('.container').children().remove();
    $(data).appendTo('.container');
  });
}

$("#most_recent").click(function () { 
  filter("recent");
  $('#most_recent').attr('style', 'font-weight: bold').css('color', '#000'); 
});
return false;
</script>
```

STOREFRONTLOAD.HTML

```
<div class="bodydiv">
    <div class="container">
    {% for i in latest_entries %}
      <div class="grid_4">
        <div class="imgcontainer">
          <img src="{{ i.item_picture.url }}" alt="" />
          <div class="overlayname">{{ i.headline }}</div>
          <div class="overlayprice">{{ i.price1 }}</div>
          </div>
        <div class="textcontainer">
        <p>{{ i.body_text }}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sellerdiv">
        <div class="sellerpic"><a href="/accounts/{{ i.author }}"><img src="{{ i.author.get_profile.get_mugshot_url }}"></a></div> 
        <div class="sellerinfo">Sold by <b>{{ i.author }}</b></div>
        <div class="hearts"><img src="/static/img/stars.png"></div>
        <div class="reviewnum"></div>
        <div class="posteddate">Posted {{ i.pub_date|timesince|upto:',' }} ago</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't stopped the default action of the link from firing: your JS works and updates the page, but then the browser follows the link and you go back to what you had. Make sure you `return false` from the end of your `click` function, or make it accept an `event` parameter and do `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Do I just add return false at the very end of the function?  I'm a little shaky with jquery

Comment: Yes, after the `$('#most_recent').attr...` line.

Comment: Thanks, that took care of that.